# Алгоритм генерации секретного ключа в чата Телеграмм

Tags: алгоритм, безопасность, rsa

Если нажать на собеседника и зайти в "Шифрование", отобразится некий ключ, длиной в `32 байта`

[image]

Интересуют как он генерируется. Это некий отпечаток? На основе чего он генерируется?

Comment: Второе вхождение не зачиркали

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если коротко, то Телеграмм [использует](https://core.telegram.org/api/end-to-end#key-generation) для создания общего секретного ключа для чата алгоритм [DH](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8_%E2%80%94_%D0%A5%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0). После этого обмен сообщений [происходит](https://core.telegram.org/api/end-to-end#sending-and-receiving-messages-in-a-secret-chat) с помощью шифра [AES](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard). Та картинка, которую вам показывает [визуализирует](https://core.telegram.org/api/end-to-end/pfs#key-visualization) отпечаток (SHA-1) первого ключа, который был получен при первоначальном обмене, а также 160 битов SHA-265 ключа (of the key in use when the secret chat was updated to layer 46)

Также интересно посмотреть [на эту статью](https://www.alexrad.me/discourse/a-264-attack-on-telegram-and-why-a-super-villain-doesnt-need-it-to-read-your-telegram-chats.html).